# Validate numbers in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping

Here's an example with a function inside a model in my Codeigniter application.

```
function is_subscriber($thread_id) {
    $this->db->query("SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE thread_id = $thread_id");
}
```

Where and how should I escape `$thread_id`? Since the database field thread_id is an integer `$thread_id` should not be surrounded by single quotes in the query. So I'm wondering how I should escape numbers in Codeigniter? Should I by my self check if `$thread_id` is a number, or is there a way to do it with Codeigniter?

I found `escape_like_str()` which escapes without adding the quotes, as opposed to escape() that adds quotes. Should I also use `escape_like_str()` for numbers?

Secondly, should I "validate" `$thread_id` in the model or in the controller?

Comment: Take a look at **[active records](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)**.

Comment: @TerryHarvey Doesn't say anything about numbers, as far as I can se.

Comment: Nothing about numbers, but it directly answers your question about escaping: "It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have to use a query from Sam Dufel's answer, just to answer your numerous questions and assumptions

> Where and how should I escape $thread_id?

A general rule is - as close to the query building as possible.
Thus, the **best** method would be to use a placeholder, as it will guarantee that the data will be properly formatted right before insertion into query.

> Since the database field thread_id is an integer $thread_id should not be surrounded by single quotes in the query.

This is not quite true. 
Only if you run mysql in strict mode, you can't use quotes.
but in general you can use quotes all the way. So, formatting numbers as strings is quite possible solution.

> So I'm wondering how I should escape numbers...

The **only** way to escape a number is to **cast** it. `intval()` is okay

> ... in Codeigniter?

if it lets you to use a placeholder - go for it.

> Should I by my self check if $thread_id is a number, or is there a way to do it with Codeigniter?

In gneral, there is no need *to check*. At the database level, only proper *formatting* needed.

> Should I also use escape_like_str() for numbers?

It will make **absolutely, definitely** no sense.
Should you use a influenza vaccine to protect your money from robbery? The same here. It's different matters.

> should I "validate" $thread_id in the model or in the controller?

First of all you have to distinguish input *validation* and database-specific *formatting*.
Second one is obligatory and unconditional, while first one is optional.
As long as this "validation" has nothing to do with DB formatting, you can do it anywhere.

Personally I'd do it in controller, and throw 404 on fail. Because it's controller to do HTTP specific actions, while model have to be environment-independent.
But again, such a validation has nothing to do with database-specific formatting, which have to be applied always.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a well written answer. So basically if I write $id = intval($id); and then use $id in my query, would that be enough?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking - yes. But to let a placeholder to do it for you is still better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The codeigniter database adapter has built-in query parameterization; it's as simple as replacing each parameter with a question mark, and passing all your variables in an array as the second argument.

```
$this->db->query("SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE thread_id = ?", array($thread_id));
```

When you set it up this way, there's no possibility of sql injection and you don't have to worry about escaping your data (at least not for the SQL portion; XSS and html escaping is still a concern)

Comment: In addition, where and how you decide to validate the actual value of `$thread_id` is really up to you. If this value is generated by user input, you'll likely have a form validation set up for it (either in a controller or model). You could also check it in the method, but be careful about how errors are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Sam's way is the proper Codeigniter way to do this. For more of a standard PHP way:

```
$thread_id = intval($thread_id);
$this->db->query("SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE thread_id = ". $thread_id);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've downvoted this answer accidentally. if you edit it, I'll be able to revert. Though, a condition looks redundant to me

Comment: @YourCommonSense The condition was redundant, good call. If $thread_id is an integer then intval($thread_id) will just equal itself. Edited.

Answer (score -1):

when using a standard query you may want to use `$this->db->escape_like_str()` like so

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = '.$this->db->escape_like_str($id).'AND user_id ='.$this->db->escape_like_str($user_id).'LIMIT 1';
```

Or:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ? AND user_id = ? LIMIT 1'
$query = $this->db->query(array($id,$user_id));
```

This methods does not validate numbers just escapes them for security , if you want to validate a number you can use PHP native function `is_numeric` or `ctype_digit` or `is_int()` you can read the PHP manual or discover your self on what you need to use . .

Comment: nope, when using a standard query they DON'T want to use escape_like_str(), as it is useless and insecure.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, have you tried reading my answer clearly i stated that 'this methods does not validate numbers but only escape them',

and for the fact that on my first paragraph of my answer a said 'you may want' . . 

sincerly yours MyCommonSense